# Programmatically Connect to Wifi device python Raspberry

Tags: python-2.7, wifi, raspberry-pi3

I am working with Raspberry PI 3.

Here I have a task to create Custom GUI to view all the available wifi connections and to connect selected wifi using python.

I am able to get all the Wifi connections through following code.

```
    import subprocess
results = subprocess.check_output(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "network"])
print(results)
results = results.decode("ascii") # needed in python 3
results = results.replace("\r","")
ls = results.split("\n")
ls = ls[4:]
ssids = []
x = 0

while x < len(ls):
    if x % 5 == 0:

        ssids.append(ls[x])
    x += 1
#print(ssids)
```

But, I am not able to get apis to connect to particular wifi.

Kindly provide me good tutorial for that If any.

Thank you guys

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No,
unfortunately not